# Remove running head in amsart

Tags: header-footer, amsart

Is it possible to remove the running head and page-numbering in an `amsart` document? I am submitting a document where there are not too many requirements, and I like how `amsart` looks like, but I need to get rid of the headers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put

```
\pagestyle{plain}
```

in the preamble.

Comment: Or `\pagestyle{empty}` since apparently there should be no numbering either.

Comment: @Gonzalo `empty` was perfect - thanks!

Comment: @Aniko: any document that has more than two pages should have page numbers.

Comment: With amsart, you'll need to say `\thispagestyle{empty}` on the first page, in addition to saying `\pagestyle{empty}` to deal with all pages after the first.

Comment: Agreed. This is an article for a "proceedings"-type collection, and the overall page numbering will be added later, I assume in the (large) margins we are supposed to leave. The final result will probably be a hodge-podge of different styles, but I am just following instructions.

Comment: write that after \maketitle

Answer (score 4):

I've found that to get no headings and no page numbers I need

```
\pagestyle{empty}
```

in the preamble, and

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

in the document test after `\maketitle`

Comment: I had to do this as well, `plain` also sufficed for me in place of `empty`